# Does the name server reported by whois get automatically updated when moving hosts?

Tags: domains

This is regarding the nameserver info shown on who.is, example:

```
name server: ns1.NS-example.net
```

When a domain is transferred to another host provider, is it possible for whois to show a nameserver from a previous host?  Does this info automatically get updated via the new server settings?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a domain is transferred from one provider to other, Name servers remain the same. You can even select which Name servers to be used when it is being transferred. It depends on what is selected when the domain is being transferred.

Comment: thank you, So the namesever on who.is has to be correct, else the website would not work.  However, the details for the admin and registrant could be out if date, if people leave a company and move on.

Comment: Why wouldn't the website work if the details of name servers vary differently on who.is? Who.is caches results so most often details won't match until they update the cache.

Comment: @user38053 WhoIs tells you who the registered owner is along with the Registrar Company.  The Nameserver is updated by the Hosting Company, not by WhoIs themselves.